Is there a JavaScript code to stop a webpage from detecting you have clicked off the tab?
I want to write a JavaScript code that stops a webpage from detecting you have clicked off the tab. I have to inject JavaScript in the webpage via Chrome extension, but the webpage pauses the execution of any JavaScript when you switch tabs or applications. Trivial solutions such as sending continous messages to the webpage does not work.
No DOM manipulation allowed such as overriding document.visibilityState.
Must be performed from service worker file and cannot change contentScript.
How can this be accomplished?
Here is the code inside a file called contentScript.js (this file cannot be modified):
function start() {
    // This function is called when the extension is now running on the webpage
    console.log("contentScript.js started")

    // Initialize list to contain logged timestamps
    let loggedTimestamps = [new Date()]

    // Get output list element
    const outputList = document.getElementById("output-stream-list")

    // Get status element
    const statusElement = document.getElementById("status")

    const log = () => {
        // Grab the current visibility state
        const visibilityState = document.visibilityState
        const isTabActive = visibilityState === 'visible'
        if (!isTabActive) {
            // Tab is not active, do not log
            return
        }

        // Get current local time 
        const now = new Date()

        // Set threshold for gap
        const threshold = 1400 // with error margin

        // Check if last timestamp was too long ago
        const lastDiff = now - loggedTimestamps[loggedTimestamps.length - 1]
        if (lastDiff > threshold) {
            // Create new list item and prepend to list
            const listItem = document.createElement("li")
            listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Tab not visible for ${lastDiff / 1000} seconds! :(`))
            outputList.prepend(listItem)
        }

        // Create new list item and prepend to list
        const logText = `${visibilityState} ${now.toLocaleTimeString()}`
        const listItem = document.createElement("li")
        listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(logText))
        outputList.prepend(listItem)

        // Log timestamp
        loggedTimestamps.push(now)

        // Determine if the logged timestamps have been continuous (ie. no gapps greater than threshold)
        let success = true
        for (let i = 1; i < loggedTimestamps.length; i++) {
            const diff = loggedTimestamps[i] - loggedTimestamps[i - 1]

            if (diff > threshold) {
                success = false
                break
            }
        }

        // Set status
        statusElement.innerText = success ? "Tab has always been active :)" : "Tab became inactive :("
        statusElement.style.color = success ? "green" : "red"
    }

    // Log every second
    setInterval(log, 1000)
}

start()

It is important to note that background.js runs as a service worker in a non-window environment.
Trivial solutions such as sending continuous messages, messing with focus elements, and DOM manipulation will not work.

It's not going to be much of a challenge if you just ask for the answer on SO.

I've never worked with chrome extensions before so I just wanna know where to look to get the answer. Not a crime to use all resources available to you

The only method is to run a script in the MAIN world that patches all the methods used by the site to detect inactivity. Either use devtools debugger to find these methods or patch everything e.g. addEventListener, onblur setter, document.hasFocus.

The script can only be run as a service worker but I understand your point. Thanks for the help anyways
